# Android Real-Time application

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm working on app the share tasks between users. By Google Cloud Messaging, I can notify the user target that he has a new task shared. The problem is : GCM does not offer a delivery guarantee. Would someone use an app like WhatsApp if he took minutes to deliver a message or not come to hand? That's my problem with GCM.

So I've got a solution : Use Socket!!!

Using Socket.oi and Node.js, my dream came become really works like magic !!!
But as nothing is free, keep a socket connection has a very high cost for the battery. Some people argue that the use of Sockets when there is no communication, nothing in or out, no cycles, so there is no consumption.

My friends, I've read a lot of text and do not know what approach should I follow. I ask your help. Soket.oi? WebSocket ???

How to maintain a connection to my server permante preserving the most of the battery?

I appreciate everyone's help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use mix of a socket connection and GCM. Both connection types do no guarantee delivery so you need to implement mechanism which checks consistency of messages history.

Simplified scenario could look like this:

1. a user launches your client
2. the client app registers at GCM and sends google id to your server.
3. the client app establishes socket connection
4. your server sends messages to a client through GCM **and** socket connection (if it is establish with particular connection)
5. each message has unique id, therefore the client could just ignore second identical message from Google of a socket connection

About not delivered messages:

When client connects to the server through socket connection it should receive response where history of messages should be put. It shouldn't be full history, it could be just last message (in case you develop chat app). Then a client just checks if he has notified user about last message or not. If not then your client makes request(http or through socket) to your server and receives undelivered messages.

Battery consumption:

Do not acquire wake lock to maintain socket connection! A device must go sleep. GCM will wake up handset.

Comment: Thank you man!!!! I've think about that... my big problem is about GCM that sometimes not delivery notifications but you turned on a lamp in my head, I just need to mature this ideia, save to DB messages and via socket control what app has know about it. THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: @lfaa you're welcome. If my answer really helped you, please mark it as solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io is good, and certainly useful in many real-time applications, but what happens when the app is terminated by the user? Or if the user restarts their phone? How would you receive notifications then?

For all purposes, GCM is good enough.

Comment: Thank you man for attention... well in case of need to keep connection alive all time, the socket object must to run inside a service where can be started by broadcast and bind by application... my big problem is how to keep connection and save battery at same time. How to control if user kill, restart and so on, we can manager it without a lot of problems... but thank you for you attention :-)

Comment: Hi, I am in same problem. Have you found any solution for this ? Any help will appreciate.